# Web Garden behaves differently depending on the user set on the application pool identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, iis, application-pool, web-garden

I have configured my website in IIS (just an ASP.NET MVC application) to use Web Garden. I have noticed that If I set its application pool identity to a domain administrator account (not local administrator account) it is working correctly. However if I set it to any non-administrator account it does not work (user gets kicked off randomly with http errors 403 and 404 (See screenshots below) and system becomes unstable because of this). So Do I need to set permissions for this non-administrator account somewhere else? or maybe... Is it mandatory to be an administrator account in order to Web Garden to work correctly? Does anyone experiencied this before? Could someone confirm this?

**LAST UPDATED 2020/11/11**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since you didn't even mention the substatus code, I think you should get started from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: @LexLi I have updated my post with some screenshoots with the mentioned http errors 403 and 404 obtained. See my last update 2020/11/11.

Comment: Like the article says, read IIS log files please. The screen shots are useless since they are not the detailed error pages.